# What is the benefit of compiling java on a linux machine over windows?

Tags: java, linux, compilation

I have a CS professor who insists compiling our java classes on a linux server before we submit our code for grading. He did this when I took him for a course in C which makes sense because I know sometimes C code will compile differently in linux over windows.

However, my understanding of the JVM is that it's platform independent. Is this true or am I missing some benefits to compiling on linux?

Comment: No, there are not benefits. It's just the JVM who plays a role, that's PI.

Comment: Only benefit you get is the default charsets are different in Windows and Linux, so if someone tries to inject some malicious content  disguised as a comment such as Unicode escapes like \u000d . you could probably figure it out . But then again Unicode processing happens before the source code processing, so i m not sure how much value does it add

Comment: Also some builds are platform dependent because of default charsets. etc

Answer (score 1):

Java is write-once-run-everywhere. That's probably one of the main reasons it was created. Java is compiled down to Byte code which is interpreted and executed by the Java Virtual Machine. Furthermore, this is translated into native code using a Just-In-Time Compilation for performance reasons.

The only reason I could think of is maybe some OS specific things hard-coded in your application? Such as "C:\some\folder\lives\here\on\windows", or in your case "/usr/local/somefile/here/i/want/to/access/on/linux". Again not sure.

Comment: Thats what I thought. I will have to ask him and see why he wants it done.

Comment: If he is making you hard code OS specific things. Challenge him! Tell him.. Listen bro, there is a `Paths` package provided by Java that can do this work for us... no really, it does exist. And make sure you have the same amount of zeal that those kids had in Peter Pan when they realized they could fly when they thought of happy thoughts. Just saying...